# Having Difficulty Finding Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm having a lot of problems with the following problem in Steven J. Leon's "Linear Algebra with Applications" 8th edition.  Problem 6.1.1.I asks the reader to "*find the eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenspaces of the following matricies*, where 1 I) is the following:

> $ \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
> 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \end{array} \right)$

Finding the eigenvalues isn't too difficult as:

> $ det(A - \lambda I) = (3 - \lambda)(1 - \lambda)(2 - \lambda)(2 - \lambda)$

Therefore the eigenvalues are: $\lambda_{1} = 1$; $\lambda_{2} = \lambda_{3} = 2$; $\lambda_{4} = 3$.  My problem though is finding the eigenspaces.  My understanding is that the eigenspaces are the solution to $N(A-\lambda_{i}I)$, is this correct?  If so, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong as my answer seems to diverge from the book's.  For instance, I'm trying to find $N(A-2I)$ and I come up with $\lbrace (\frac{1}{2}, 1, 0, 0)^{T} \rbrace$ as a basis (by this method http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi.  However, the book's answer corresponding to $\lambda_{2} = \lambda_{3}$ is $(0,0,1,0)^{T}$.

Could someone lend me a hand here?  My problem with finding eigenvectors is driving me a bit batty.

Comment: Here's a little something. Because the matrix is block diagonal, you could look for the eigenvectors of $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}3&0\\4&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ separately, and $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ separately.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how this helps.  Do you know what it is I'm doing incorrectly? I'm getting the feeling there is something wrong with my approach.

Comment: @BrotherJack: Certainly $(A-2I)(1/2, 1, 0, 0)^T  \ne  0$ -- but it's hard to say what's wrong with the calculation that led you to believe it would be zero, because you're not showing that calculation.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't just mixed up two calculations? $(\frac{1}{2},1,0,0)^T$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $3$, so it is a basis for the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each case, find the kernel of $A-\lambda I$. For example, when $\lambda = 1$, you have:

$$A-\lambda I = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$$

Consider vectors of the form $[u,v,w,x]^{\top}$. We can multiply $A-\lambda I$ on the right by this vector and we obtain $[2u,4u,w+x,x]^{\top}$. This belongs to the kernel if and only if $2u=0$, $4u=0$, $w+x=0$ *and* $x=0$. Clearly $u=0$ and $x=0$. Once we impose $x=0$, the condition $w+x=0$ becomes $w=0$. Hence the kernel vectors are of the form $[0,v,0,0]^{\top}$. You are free to choose $v$. The eigenspace is then the $v$-axis. Do the same for $\lambda = 2$ and $\lambda=3$.

Answer (score 2):

We have the following:

$v_1 = (1, 2, 0, 0),   \lambda_1 = 3$

$v_2 = (0, 0, -1, 0),   \lambda_2 = 2$

$v_3 = (0, 0, 0, 0),   \lambda_3 = 2 \rightarrow v_3 = {0, 0, 0, -1}$

$v_4 = (0, 1, 0, 0),   \lambda_4 = 1$

Lets take an example for $\lambda_2 = 2$. We solve for:

$$|A -\lambda I|v = \begin{pmatrix}
3 - \lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 \\4 & 1- \lambda & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 2-\lambda & 1 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 2-\lambda\end{pmatrix}v = 0$$

We have:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\4 & -1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}v = 0$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Excellent example...leading by example. Needs (+++++'s)

Answer (score 1):

You said that you want to find $N(A-\lambda_iI)$ so we can do it directly:
$N= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
3-2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 1-2 &0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2-2 & 1\\
0 &0&0&2  \end{array} \right) $
simplyfing it we get the following equalations for given $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x\\
y\\
z\\
w\end{array} \right) $ in the space:
I x=0,
II 4x-y=0=>y=4*0=0,
III w=0. so taking y=1 we get the same answer as in your book.

Answer (score 1):

The hint Michael Grant gave allows you to "split" the transformation apart into two block diagonal pieces. If you find an eigenvector for the upper left hand block, and an eigenvector for the lower right hand block, then by padding them with zeros you can make eigenvectors for the entire matrix.

So, concentrating on the lower left hand block (whose eigenvalues are both 2), you look at this:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=2\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}
$$
This yields the equation $2a+b=2a$ , whence $b=0$ and the remaining expression $2a=2a$ means that $a$ is free to be whatever value. So, you may as well pick something simple like $a=1$, thus $[1,0]^T$ is an eigenvector for this block. Padding with zeros where the upper left hand block would multiply, you get $[0,0,1,0]^T$  as an eigenvector.

Likewise in the other block:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\4&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=3\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}
$$
This yields $4a+b=3b$ (and $3a=3a$, which says nothing) telling you that $4a=2b$ is the only constraint to be satisfied. You may as well pick $a=2$ and $b=1$, so that $[2,1]$ is an eigenvector for $3$.

Finally

$$
\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\4&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=1\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}
$$

Yields $4a+b=b$, so that $a=0$, but $b$ is free to be chosen, so it may as well be $1$, so that $[0,1]^T$ is an eigenvector for $1$.

Padding the two vectors we found: $[0,1,0,0]$ and $[2,1,0,0]$ are two more eigenvectors of the whole matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you take your $(A-\lambda I_4)\underline x=(A-2I_4)\underline x=\underline{0}$ Then you get 
$$\left( \begin{array}{cccc|c}
3-2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
4 & 1-2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2-2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2-2 & 0\end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
4 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array} \right)$$
So clearly the solution for $x_1=x_2=x_4=0$ and $x_3$ is independent. Thus the solution vector is $(0,0,1,0)^T$